# How to propagate exception on event-driven/message queue microservice?

Tags: exception, rabbitmq, microservices, message-queue, event-driven

It's very straightforward on HTTP call between microservices to propagate exception to caller/front-end.

But how to propagate exception on event-driven/message queue (ie. RabbitMQ) microservice to the caller/front-end?

Comment: Similar to [Dealing with exceptions in an event-driven world](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49955554/697630)

Comment: Please clarify your thoughts, as propagating an exception through HTTP or a queue is straightforward IMO in both cases

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) which is much more powerful solution for microservice orchestration and provides exception handling propagation across long running operations out of the box.

It offers a lot of other advantages over using queues for your use case.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.