# Co-ordinating processes in a microservices world

Tags: microservices

I was reading the accepted answer on this SO post: [Orchestrating microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117570/orchestrating-microservices) and my question is, how does one monitor a process using the choreographed approach? The author of the quoted book writes:

> One approach I like for dealing with this is to build a monitoring system that explicitly matches the view of the business process in [the workflow], but then tracks what each of the services does as independent entities, letting you see odd exceptions mapped onto the more explicit process flow.

What I would like to know is, how exactly does this monitoring system work? I have tried to research this but wasn't able to find anywhere that properly describes what I am trying to understand.

The way I am thinking of this is that, we store some kind of representation of the process like *"here is the work that needs to be done"* and then, as that is done, have each service update it accordingly. We can then have something like a cron that monitors this and sends another message if has not been completed. After trying five times say, and it has still not been done, we can deduce that the process has failed and reply accordingly to the caller. Is this an accurate interpretation of what the author is alluding to?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use **request id** and **correlation id**.

A **request id** is used to link the caller to the callee. Everytime a service wants to call another one, it generates a unique id (a UUID) and set it into the `X-Request-ID` header. The service that receives the request reads the request id.

A **correlation id** is use to trace a sequence of requests, for example service A invokes service B, and service B invokes three times service C. When a service receives a request, it reads the correlation id from the `X-Correlation-ID` header. If the header is absent, the service generates a correlation id. Then the service includes the correlation id into all the requests it makes in reaction of the received request. In our example, the call from A to B, and the three calls from B to C have all the same correlation id.

Those headers are [common non-standard request fields.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields).

Now all the services must log each request sent and received with the request id and the correlation id:

- By filtering your logs on a request id, you will see which service sent it and which one receives it. If you have more requests sent than received, some requests are lost.
- By filtering on a correlation id, you will see the whole sequence of requests triggered by the initial request. Keeping an eye on the longest sequence may alert you about poor designs where a single request triggers dozen of other requests in the system. It also helps you in understanding why a single request takes so long to be processed : it may be caused by requests to other services.