# orchestration vs choreography in Micro service architecture

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, orchestration, choregraphe

In the Micro service architecture ,  I was reading the concepts the orchestration and choreography. Is any guidelines/suggestions for choosing the  Choreography and Orchestration?

Comment: Please check [Orchestrating microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117570/orchestrating-microservices?rq=1)

Answer (score 9):

**Orchestration** can be linked with how Orchestra performs i.e when you have control over all the actors in a process - when they're all in one domain of control and you can control the flow of activities. This is ofcourse most often when you're specifying a business process that will be enacted inside one organisation that you have control over.

[image: Orchestration vs. Choreography]

**Choreography** is a way of specifying how two or more parties - none of which has any control over the other parties' processes, or perhaps any visibility of those processes - can coordinate their activities and processes to share information and value. Use choreography when coordination across domains of control/visibility is required. You can think of choreography, in a simple scenario, as like a network protocol. It dictates acceptable patterns of requests and responses between parties.

You can choose between Orchestration and Choreography in your Microservices based on what fits best for your use case based something similar lines of above mentioned explanation.